# AWS DynamoDB + multiple Titan servers: Is this setup possible?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, scalability, titan

I want to create a web application which is using a graph database hosted as part of the [Amazon Web Services (AWS)](https://aws.amazon.com/). As far as I understand, to use a Graph database with [AWS DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) as storage backend, you need to run a Titan server. Such a server can be set up on an [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance.

Now, to remain scalable, I will eventually want to deploy multiple such instances behind (a couple of) load balancers. The question that arises is:

**Can multiple Titan DB instances work with the same, shared storage backend (such as DynamoDB)?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Titan Server is a [Gremlin Server](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#gremlin-server), which is based on Netty. You configure it with a graph properties file which points to your storage backend (DynamoDB) and indexing backend (optional). As long as you use the same graph properties file for each Titan Server, it should work as your described architecture.

Comment: Thank you Jason! What a funny coincidence, I'm just studying your Java example of Titan on github.